# History command in graphic interface of OS

Tags: 14.04, graphics, history, execute-command

Does Ubuntu store a history of command executed in the graphic interface (not in a shell session)?

For example if, by mouse, I click on System Settings, then click on Network, do these steps correspond to commands (for example exec commands)?

If yes, does Ubuntu track these commands in a log file?

Answer (score 0):

Each of the programs that you interact with in a GUI typically have their own logs for various things. AFAIK there is no way to find a universal log of everything you do in a GUI like you would with the history command.

Perhaps if you enable debugging in your Desktop Manager you could get additional output, but each program that you interact with will have its own logs somewhere.

If you are using unity, you can learn more about debugging [here](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/Unity/FilingBugs).

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately, many actions of GUI programs are implemented in the program itself, not using external commands.

So that does not exist, and is not easy to implement.

But if you just want to monitor(*It's not log file, it's video record*) your GUI actions for some time you can screencast your Desktop using some apps such as [kazam](https://apps.ubuntu.com/cat/applications/kazam/) ,or [record my desktop](https://apps.ubuntu.com/cat/applications/gtk-recordmydesktop/)...

Answer (score 0):

Yes when clicking on system setting in the background it's associated with a command , because in ubuntu we just invoke some script(i.e, execute a file) to do some activities , so you can also open system settings from Terminal  **for versions >= 14.04 -> unity-control-center else gnome-control center**  , so this way it works it's associated with some command always in ubuntu . There are some applications which record our activities like **Activity Journal** so ubuntu must be saving our activities that we do somewhere but i don't exactly know the location where they were stored .

**For  applications in ubuntu there is a graphical view , go to /usr/share/applications/ you will find icons of every applications like in windows then right-click properties so that you can see the command associated with it . **